# Internal ext4 quotas (reserved inode) and rpc.rquotad export

Tags: nfs, ext4, quota, rpc

When doing a quotacheck on my NFS server, i got a message to switch quotas to internal ext4 format.
I did it, but now rpc.rquotad noes not work anymore and quotas are not anymore exported to clients.
Seems rpc.rquotad not compatible with ext4 internal quotas.

Is there an alternative solution to export quotas to nfs clients with ext4 internal quotas?

Thanks!

Comment: system : Debian 11

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
With internal quota, mount options are useless so i remove them.
But Debian startup script for rpc.rquotad still check them before start:

```
# check if quota are enabled
need_rquotad=0
if test -f /etc/exports && grep -q '^/' /etc/exports /etc/exports.d/* 2>/dev/null; then
        if **grep -q '^[^#]*quota' /etc/fstab;** then # normal quota option
                need_rquotad=1
        elif grep -q '^[^#]*qnoenforce' /etc/fstab; then # xfs non-enforced quota
                need_rquotad=1
        fi
fi
```

So just put back quota mount options in fstab solve the problem.